# set DNS entry for hostname for the DD-WRT DNS router itself

Tags: dnsmasq, dd-wrt

I'm trying to set a DD-WRT router to reply to DNS requests with it's own hostname (via the DD-WRT router's DNSMasq daemon).  **I can set other local hostnames (using *Static Leases* section) and these are returned in DNS queries from the DD-WRT router.   But adding the DD-WRT router hostname to it's own mapping of DNS *name → IP* results in failed DNS hostname lookups.**

I'm able to create DNS entries for other hosts on the local network.  I did this using by adding entries under *Static Leases* (under *Services* → *Services* → *Services Management* → *DHCP Server* → *Static Leases*).  Each entry consists of *MAC Addresss*, *Hostname*, *IP Address*, *Client Lease Time*.  However, an entry for the DD-WRT router itself has no affect (yes, using the LAN-facing MAC Address of the DD-WRT router).

#### Related DHCP and DNSMasq settings

- *LAN Domain* has string "`mydomain`"
- *Used Domain* is "*LAN & WLAN*"
- *DNSMasq* is *Enable*
- *Local DNS* is *Enable*
- *Query DNS in Strict Order* is *Enable*

For example, there is an *Static Leases* entry for "`PC1`".  From a different domain host (computer on the same LAN) I can successfully do

```
$ ping PC1.mydomain
```

Yet, a similar *Static Leases* entry "`myrouter`" exists for the LAN MAC of the DD-WRT router (yes, I am aware the DD-WRT LAN will not request a LAN-side IP via DHCP.  The router has a static IP 192.168.1.1.  I was trying this to achieve parity with the successful case).

#### Additional DNSMasq Options

Also, I added to *Additional DNSMasq Options* these lines

```
local=/mydomain/
expand-hosts
```

Then I restarted *dnsmasq*

```
$ stopservice dnsmasq
$ startservice dnsmasq
```

#### Still fails

Yet, name lookup for *myrouter.mydomain* still fails

```
$ ping myrouter.mydomain
ping: myrouter.mydomain: Name or service not known
```

Oddly, I did not have this name lookup problem before a recent upgrade of the DD-WRT router.

Answer (score 1):

In section *Additional DNSMasq Options* (under *Services* → *Services* → *Services Management* → *DHCP Server* → *Static Leases*), add the following line

```
address=/myrouter.mydomain/192.168.1.1
```

The `address` parameter is explained at the [dnsmasq man page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) (search for "`--address=`").
Suggestion is from [this old forum post](https://forum.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=686175).